# Share Extension issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

all I am working on Share Extension working fine, But I need like suppose

1. if I click  more than one video don't want to show my App in share
   list.
2. if I want to show my app only in case of image or video.(not image
   and video.). I am using below query in .plist

   ```
       <dict>
       <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
       <string>SUBQUERY (
           extensionItems,
           $extensionItem,
           SUBQUERY (
           $extensionItem.attachments,
           $attachment,
           ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
           ).@count &lt;= 10).@count &gt;= 1
           OR
           SUBQUERY(extensionItems, $extensionItem, SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, SUBQUERY($attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers, $uti, NOT $uti UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" AND NOT $uti UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.file-url" AND $uti UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text").@count &gt;= 1).@count &gt;= 1).@count &gt;= 1
           OR
           SUBQUERY(extensionItems,$extensionItem,SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments,$attachment,ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.movie").@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count AND $extensionItem.attachments.@count &lt;= 1 ).@count == 1
       </string>
       </dict>
   ```

above query working for images but not  `public.movie` can anybody help me out. and also share extension is visible in all types. i.e. vcards, contacts etc I need only text, photo, and Video.

Answer (score 0):

Change count 10 to 1, in the below part of your subquery  :

```
...
$attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
        ).@count &lt;= 10).@count &gt;= 1
...
```

to

```
...
$attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
        ).@count &lt;= 1).@count &gt;= 1
...
```

For rest of items movie, urls its fine.